# Upload more than one file aspx.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, image-uploading, multifile-uploader

I have the following HTML source:

```
 <form name="AddTrack" id="add_track_form" action="AddTrack.aspx" method="post" runat="server">


       <input type="file" name="file1"/><br />
            <input type="file" style="margin-right: 52px;" name="file2" /><br />
            <input type="file" style="margin-right: 52px;" name="file3" /><br />
            <input type="file" style="margin-right: 52px;" name="file4" /><br />
        <button type="submit" class="blue-button">הוסף מסלול</button>
    </form>
```

With this ASPX - C# code:

```
if (Request.ContentLength != 0)
{
    int Size = Request.Files[0].ContentLength / 1024;
    if (Size <= 512)
    {

        string LocalFile = Request.Files[0].FileName;
        int LastIndex = LocalFile.LastIndexOf(@"\") + 1;
        string File = LocalFile.Substring(LastIndex, LocalFile.Length - LastIndex);
        string Path = Server.MapPath(" ../images/tracks") + "..\\" + File;
        Request.Files[0].SaveAs(Path);
        Response.Write(@"The file was saved: " + Path);
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("The file is too big !");
    }
}
else
{
    Response.Write("Unknown Error !");
}
```

If I upload one file it works great, but I upload there is more than one upload input it don't work.

My question is why and how can I fix it?

Comment: What do you mean saying it does not work?

Comment: Define "don't work."  What is the actual runtime behavior?  Are there any error messages?  What is in `Request.Files`?  When you inspect the form post with browser tools (Firebug, etc.) what actually gets posted to the server?

Comment: I got this error message: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was 
System.Collections.Specialized.NameObjectCollectionBase.BaseGet(Int32 index)

Comment: On which line are you getting that error?

Comment: is this posted complete code of file upload?

Comment: I got the error in this line :     int Size = Request.Files[0].ContentLength / 1024;
Yes, this is the complete code

Comment: Are you sure error rise when you upload more than one file? it looks more like it happens when NO files uploaded.

Comment: Now I see that it doesn't work at all, but in other page with one file upload it works... I don't know what is going on here

Comment: Does that error rise after you submit a form or even when you simply open that page?

Comment: Can you show full HTML of that form? Possibly, you have some not closed tag or something else and your HTML is broken and inputs appear to be outside the form and not submitted. Also, ensure that you have set `method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, you just need to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your form:

```
 <form name="AddTrack" id="add_track_form" action="AddTrack.aspx" method="post" runat="server" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2

> The content type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" is inefficient
>   for sending large quantities of binary data or text containing
>   non-ASCII characters. **The content type "multipart/form-data" should be
>   used for submitting forms that contain files, non-ASCII data, and
>   binary data.**

You are not using `asp:FileUpload` control which adds that enctype automatically, so you should do that manually.

```
for(int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++) {

    int Size = Request.Files[i].ContentLength / 1024;
    if (Size <= 512)
    {
       string LocalFile = Request.Files[i].FileName;
    //.....
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Now there is now error, but how can I upload more than one file? maybe with for loop?

Comment: See updated answer. Something like that should work. Just put everything inside foreach loop and replace all `Request.Files[0]` with `f` (or how you will call that variable)

Comment: Thank you very much, but now I got this error  :
 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.HttpPostedFile' to 'System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase'


on this line :foreach (HttpPostedFile f in Request.Files)

Why?

Comment: Hm. Strange. But check out updated answer. That is another approach. Also, you can simply try to change `foreach (HttpPostedFile f in Request.Files) {` to `foreach (HttpPostedFileBase f in Request.Files) {`

Comment: But wait, do you really have HttpPostedFile in foreach statement? Maybe you have there HttpPostedFileBase? Request.Files contains HttpPostedFiles object and that error should not appear with my code.

Comment: I don't think so, I'm a studend and learning this subject so I don't know very well everything, with the FOR loop it is better, the *only* problem is that the smae file upload, and the other files aren't... why? (sorry for all of this questions..)

Comment: Only small files are uploaded because of this conditionL `if (Size <= 512)
    {` Which accepts only files smaller than 512Kb

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use this `uploadify library`, it's free

Because basic Upload file asp.net don't offer possibility of multiple downloading

link : http://www.uploadify.com/download/

Comment: Thanks, so there is no a simple solution? 
and cause this error?

Comment: That is only a client side library. And it has nothing common with server side where error rise

Comment: it's easy and reusable to use developed component such as uploadify